# Automatically include javascript for layout files

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I've got just two views on my very simple application:

```
app/views/layouts/alpha.html.erb
app/views/layouts/beta.html.erb
```

I have 'corresponding' coffeescript files for them:

```
app/assets/javascripts/alpha.js.coffee #-> console.log 'hi, im from alpha'
app/assets/javascripts/beta.js.coffee  #-> console.log 'hi, im from beta'
```

However, upon visting I get no messages in my console and visiting beta I get no messages in my console. How do I automatically load these files?

Comment: In app/views/layouts/alpha.html.erb add a line like this: <%= javascript_include_tag "alpha" %> and in app/views/layouts/beta.html.erb
 add this: javascript_include_tag "app/assets/javascripts/beta %>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the following lines:

For the **alpha.html.erb:**

Add at the bottom of your layout:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "alpha" %>
```

And the same for the **beta.html.erb**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "beta" %>
```

That should do the trick.